# jQuery <select>: how to get $(this.id) :first?

Tags: jquery, select

Normally, we get first  value that way:

```
$("#color option:first").val()
```

But I need something like

```
$(this.id option:first).val()
```

and of course it doesn't work.

Comment: Although Kobi's answer is the right way to do it, your way is doable too: `$('#' + this.id + ' option:first').val()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("option:first", this).val()
```

Another option is `find` (`children` may work as well, depending on your structure):

```
$(this).find("option:first").val()
```